# If hasClass does not working

Tags: jquery

i have an problem to check If hasClass, but i don't understand why it would not work.
I want, when the second DIV inside another DIV has the Class "in" do Something.

jQuery

```
if ( jQuery(".panel div:nth-child(2)").hasClass("in") ) {
    jQuery(this).css("margin-top","200px");
    console.log("has");
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"></div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="accordion-body collapse in"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: Sorry the Class come, when I open the Accordion.

Comment: You're checking for a class that's not in the HTML. How does that work?

Comment: are you looking for the class `.in` or for a class that contains the substring `in`?

Comment: i have edit it. i look for the class .in

Comment: your code works fine according to your requirements. it *"Does Something"*. - it writes "has" in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If conditions are just block level statement and You can't use `$(this)` to refer to the if block as a scope. So, you need to use the selector itself like:

```
if ( jQuery(".panel div:nth-child(2)").hasClass("in") ) {
    jQuery(".panel div:nth-child(2)").css("margin-top","200px");
    console.log("has");
};
```

---

Simplified version:

```
var selector  = jQuery(".panel div:eq(1)");
if(selector.hasClass("in")){
  selector.css("margin-top","200px");
}
```

I've used [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq) selector as it is jQuery selector than nth-child.

Comment: Or, better yet, get the element a single time before the `if` statement and store it in a `var` so you're not querying the DOM twice.